# How to retrieve all values in dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following Dictionary

```
public static Dictionary<string, List<int>> termDocumentIncidenceMatrix = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
```

I want to print all values in it , How i can make it ? 
I found `KeyValuePair` but can't recognize in my program ?
Can anyone give me bit of code or link ?

Comment: `string.Join(";", termDocumentIncidenceMatrix.Select(kvp => kvp.Key + ":" +  string.Join(",", kvp.Value)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (var term in termDocumentIncidenceMatrix)
{
    // Print the string (your key)
    Console.WriteLine(term.Key);

    // Print each int in the value
    foreach (var i in term.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print all values of the dictionary, you can use:

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<string,List<int>>{{"A",new List<int>{1,2}},{"B",new List<int>{3,4}}};

var integersList = dict.Values.SelectMany(it => it);

foreach (var item in integersList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```